# What does DateTimeOffset.Now.Offset.ToString() return when in daylight savigs time in the UK

Tags: c#, utc, gmt, datetimeoffset

so I know the function `DateTimeOffset.Now.Offset` returns the offset from UTC and from wikipedia it states that GMT and UTC are the same. Therefore I would guess that `DateTimeOffset.Now.Offset.ToString()` would always return `00:00:00` if your timezone is (UTC) London. Am I correct in thinking this or would it return `01:00:00` when in daylight savings time?

Comment: Don't you have a compiler? Why don't you try and see?

Comment: I'm not sure how I can test it? I changed my date to mid april (daylight savings) but the time obviously remains the same. I'd guess if UTC = GMT then it should return `00:00:00`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> DateTimeOffset.Now.Offset.ToString() would always return 00:00:00 if
>   your timezone is UTC.

Right. From documentation of [`DateTimeOffset.Offset` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.offset(v=vs.110).aspx);

> The difference between the current DateTimeOffset object's time value
>   and Coordinated Universal Time (UTC).

As you can see, it is normal to get `00:00:00` since London is [UTC±00:00](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_UTC_time_offsets#UTC.C2.B100:00.2C_Z) which is what we are expected.

> Am I correct in thinking this or would it return `01:00:00` when in
>   daylight savings time?

Exactly. From Wikipedia page of [Daylight saving time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time);

> Typically, users of DST adjust clocks forward **one hour** near the start
>   of spring and adjust them backward in the autumn to "normal" or
>   regular time.

By the way, you *can't* change your offset value with creating a `Datetime` which it is in your daylight saving time. OffSet value can be change only with changing your time zone manually or with daylight saving time. Your `DateTimeOffset` *still* has the same offset value *even* if you create it when times that daylight saving time.

Yes, UTC and GMT are the same. Just "GMT" term are not using most of computer science community.

Comment: Thanks for the help. For anyone else wondering this [link](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/bst) provides concise information